# How to redirect a specific user to a question answer page on login in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two users in my laravel project.
1) Super user with group_id 1
2) Normal user with group_id 2
   When a super user login for first time, he must be redirected to a specific page(SuperUserLogs) where he will be asked 3 question about his name, employee id and work order number. He can't visit other pages until he submit the answers. On submit he will be redirected to home page.
   while normal user on login will be redirected to home page.

I have made a Middleware name superuser.php. When a user login it successfully tell me whether user is super user or normal user.

In my Middleware SuperUser

```
class SuperUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //Super User user_group_id is 1
        if(Auth::user()->user_group_id==1)
        {

            //redirect to some SuperUserLogs to answer questions

            return redirect('/SuperUser/superuserlogs');

        }

        return $next($request);

    }

}
```

When i login as SuperUser. it give me the following error.
This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 
redirected you too many times.

When SuperUser login, he must be redirected to SuperUserLog page to answer question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is also a request, which will then redirect again, and again.
Only redirect if the route you're following isn't already '/SuperUser/superuserlogs'.

Comment: ```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
$currentPath= Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();

            if($currentPath != "SuperUser/superuserlogs"){
                return redirect('/SuperUser/superuserlogs');
            }
```

using this, it work for me.

But now on submit it again redirect me to same SuperUserLog page. How i resolve this issue ?

Comment: I think there are 3 cases in which the redirect does not need to happen, that you should check for in your if statement: 
1) if the route itself is '/SuperUser/superuserlogs', 
2) The route of your form submit, 
3) if the questions are already answered (you can put that as a boolean in your User model).

Comment: I think 3rd case will solve my issue? how can i handle it? I am thinking about sessions.

Comment: Issue is fixed. On submit form in "/SuperUser/superuserlogs", I store current user id in session and than in my middleware "SuperUser" I checked the id in session with current user id. If its not equal it will redirect to "/SuperUser/superuserlogs". If its equal mean questions are already answered and it will redirect to home page.

Answer (score 1):

The redirects are made by LoginController.php file. In this file you can find a property:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

There is a suggestion to remove this property and add a method as follow:

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    //

}
```

So, you can define a logic to handle users with different roles to different paths:

```
public function redirectTo(){

    // User role
    $role = Auth::user()->role->name; 

    // Check user role
    switch ($role) {
        case 'Manager':
                return '/dashboard';
            break;
        case 'Employee':
               return '/projects';
            break; 
        default:
                return '/login'; 
            break;
    }
}
```

Be sure to include class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth in LoginController.php.

As you can see, the author shows us a switch statement that checks user role and executes the part where user role is specified.

See more details here:

https://codeburst.io/learn-how-to-redirect-authenticated-users-to-corresponding-path-in-laravel-dd613e2f9e3

cheers!